# Sum up everything except query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Patient table that is like this for account 999888 that only needs for the payment_amount that is not zero to sum up the payment_amount2:

| NRV | Code | Payment_amount | payment_amount2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Z01 | 1111111 | 99 | 100 |
| Z01 | 1111111 | 0 | 150 |
| Z01 | 1111111 | 44 | 200 |

Here is my query that I am trying to use:

```
select sum(payment_amount2) as payment_amount2 from patient
where payment_amount!=0
group by patient.account_number,patient.nrv
```

However similarly I might have account 991991 that only has a $0 payment_amount and I need to sum up payment_amount2.

| NRV | Code | Payment_amount | payment_amount2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Z01 | 1111111 | 0 | 150 |

Here is the query for that:

```
select sum(payment_amount2) as payment_amount2 from patient
where payment_amount=0
group by patient.account_number,patient.nrv
```

I also may have a scenario like this for account 989111 where the payment_amount can be canceled by another payment_amount if they are of equal amount which then I cannot include that payment_amount2 in the sum:

| NRV | Code | Payment_amount | payment_amount2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Z01 | 1111111 | 99 | 100 |
| Z01 | 1111111 | 0 | 150 |
| Z01 | 1111111 | 44 | 200 |
| Z01 | 1111111 | -44 | 155 |

My question is how do I combine the two queries?

Comment: Are you interested in negative numbers?

Comment: Please supply sample data that contains the actual data in question.

Comment: @RossBush negative numbers are fine just as long as payment_amount2 is summed up correctly.

Comment: tag your DB pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just divide the business cases using case expressions:

```
with cte  (account, NRV ,Code   ,Payment_amount,    payment_amount2) 
as (
select '999888', 'Z01'  ,'1111111'  ,99,    100
union all select '999888' ,'Z01'    ,'1111111', 0   ,150
union all select '999888', 'Z01'    ,'1111111', 44  ,200
  union all select '999888', 'Z01'  ,'1111111', -44 ,155
  union all select '991991', 'Z01'  ,'1111111', 0   ,150
)
,cte2 as (
select 
account, 
NRV,
Code,
abs(payment_amount) abs,
count(case when payment_amount > 0 then 1 end) as p,
count(case when payment_amount < 0 then 1 end) as n,
sum(payment_amount2) as payment_amount2
from cte
group by abs(payment_amount),account, NRV,Code
),
cte3 as (
select 
*,case when abs = 0 then 0
         when p = n then 0
         when p > n then p - n
         when p < n then n - p end as pn
from cte2
  ), cte4 as (
  select 
  account,nrv,code,
  case when count(*) over (partition by account) = 1 
  then payment_amount2
  when pn <> 0 then payment_amount2 end as payment_amount2
  from cte3
    )
    select account,nrv,sum(payment_amount2) as payment_amount2
    from cte4
    group by account,nrv
```

Comment: This seems to work for me. Can you show me how I can use this in an SQL UPDATE Statement if I am linking the Patient table by "account" column to another table using its "account" column?

Comment: That's a separate question, and it's unrelated to the original question unfortunately, and probably requires some other details not mentioned before

Comment: Well I figured it out thanks to your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Break it down by most restrictive to least restrictive first. This will give you the flow. Then, build out the case, again, from most restrictive to least restrictive.

I am not sure about the last case, so will build it out with the first two cases.

```
case when account = '999888' and payment_amount != 0 then payment_amount
else when account = '991991' and payment_amount = 0 then payment_amount2
else ...
else 0 --the default case.
end
```

We then throw that in a sum.

```
sum(
    case when account = '999888' and payment_amount != 0 then payment_amount
    else when account = '991991' and payment_amount = 0 then payment_amount2
    else ...
    else 0
end) as payment_amount2
```

Just make sure it is readable, large cases make it hard to maintain the query if you don't keep it readable.